# Parse a non-window URL using $location.search

Tags: angularjs

I'm using

```
$rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, newurl, oldurl){...})
```

How do I parse newurl using $locationsearch despite it not being the current url?

Comment: Here's how Angular does it ~ https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9360aa2d27fd4b35c377ecff3eea2a656ecf7114/src/Angular.js#L1344